# Codeigniter using sessions in Database class

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

I need your help in codeigniter project. I want to use session to dynamic change data base on databse file in config folder. 
I do $db['default']['database'] = $_SESSION['db_name'], in config file but dont work.
The login page Should check which other database access to do login.

Is it possible to change the connection before selecting the database?

Login page

```
public function login(){
if(!$this->session->userdata('id_funcionario') || !$this->session->userdata('logado')){ 

    $this->db->database= "test";
    $this->session->destroy();
    $subdomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];  
    $this->db->select("database");
    $this->db->where("subdomain", $subdomain);
    $access = $this->db->get("table")->row();
    $this->session->set_userdata("database", $access->database);
    $this->load->view('/geral/login'); 

}else{
    $url = base_url('home');
    header("Location: $url ");

}
```

}

The login page works!

The data are send for AJAX to:

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->library('session');

    }
public function toLog()
    { 
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $pass= md5($this->input->post('pass'));

        $this->db->database = $this->session->userdata('database');
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('usu_email',$email);
        $this->db->where('usu_pass',$pass);
        $usuario = $this->db->get()->result();
```

But I do not know how to change the name of the database on time of the query. I have tried and it remains unchanged.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


/**
 * Database Driver Class
 *
 * This is the platform-independent base DB implementation class.
 * This class will not be called directly. Rather, the adapter
 * class for the specific database will extend and instantiate it.
 *
 */

    class CI_DB_driver {

    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $hostname;
    var $database;

.......

    /**
     * Constructor.  Accepts one parameter containing the database
     * connection settings.
     *
     * @param array
     */
    function __construct($params)
    {
        if (is_array($params))
        {
            foreach ($params as $key => $val)
            {
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $this->database = $CI->session->userdata('database');

        log_message('debug', 'Database Driver Class Initialized');
    }....
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will answer your question but it might help.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases

You can switch databases at any time just by using

```
$this->db->db_select($database2_name);
```

In your code though, you destroy the session and then attempt to set a session data variable. The session has been destroyed so that variable will not be set anywhere until a new session is created.

I would suggest that you set your databases as groups in the config file and switch groups. Alternatively you can connect to both at once as described in the docs and select which one to use by using the database object to set your queries to. Although to be honest I really think that perhaps you need to revisit your logic as setting a database in a session variable seems a rather strange way to approach any problem IMHO.

But, if in your controller, you read your session variable, check it is a recognized database for your system, check user is allowed to access it, then connect to it, should work fine. You should not be trying to access the session data in a config file as at the time of reading the config files the session data will probably not be available.